# why is this not working writing ValueError (though i used Tango_with_django book 1.9)?

Tags: python, django

Am using Django 2.0.2 for Django 1.9 Tutorial and couldn't figure out what the problem was after reconstruct my URL. Error Display (The view rango.views.category didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.)

```
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from rango.models import Category, Page


def index(request):
    # Obtain the context from the HTTP request.
    context = RequestContext(request)

    # Query the database for a list of ALL categories currently stored.
    # Order the categories by no. likes in descending order.
    # Retrieve the top 5 only - or all if less than 5.

    # Place the list in our context_dict dictionary which will be passed to the template engine.
    # Query for categories - add the list to our context dictionary.
    category_list = Category.objects.order_by('-likes')[:5]
    context_dict = {'categories': category_list}

    # looping through each category returned, and create a URL attribute.
    # This attribute stores an encoded URL (e.g spaces replaced with underscores).
    for category in category_list:
        category.url = category.name.replace(' ', '_')

    # Render the response and return to the client!
    return render_to_response('rango/index.html', context_dict, context)


def category(request, category_name_url):
    # Request our context from the request passed to us.
    context = RequestContext(request)
    # Change underscores in the category name to spaces.
    # URLs don't handle spaces well, so we encode them as underscores.
    # We can then simply replace the underscores with spaces again to get the name.
    category_name = category_name_url.replace('_', ' ')
    # Create a context dictionary which we can pass to the template rendering engine.
    # We start by containing the name of the category passed by the user.
    context_dict = {'category_name': category_name}

    try:
        # Can we find a category with the given name?
        #  If we can't, the .get() method raises a DoesNotExist exception.
        # So the .get() method returns one model instance or raises an exception.
        category = Category.objects.get(name=category_name)
        # Retrieve all of the associated pages.
        #  Note that filter returns >= 1 model instance.
        pages = Page.objects.filter(category=category)
        # Adds our results list to the template context under name pages.
        context_dict['pages'] = pages
        # We also add the category object from the database to the context dictionary.
        # We'll use this in the template to verify that the category exists.
        context_dict['category'] = category

    except Category.DoesNotExist:
        # We get here if we didn't find the specified category.
        # Don't do anything - the template displays the "no category" message for us.
        pass
        # Go render the response and return it to the client.
        return render_to_response('rango/category.html', context_dict, context)
```

`urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    re_path(r'^category/(?P<category_name_url>\w+)/$', views.category, name='category'),
]
```

Comment: You're missing return within the `try`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your contribution...  Problem Solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put more faith into error messages. It says your `category()` function did not return a value, because it did not return a value. Its `return` is indented to the same level as `pass` and thus it belongs to the exception handler. Indent it to the level of the `except` keyword.

Comment: Thanks so much for your contribution...  Problem Solved